# Angular request api along with token

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, facebook, laravel

In my angular application, this function return the result of:

```
{"error":"token_not_provided"}
```

The function is

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('authApp')
        .controller('UserController', UserController);

    function UserController($http,$auth,$window) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.users;
        vm.error;

        vm.getUsers = function() {
            //console.log($window.sessionStorage.token);
            // This request will hit the index method in the AuthenticateController
            // on the Laravel side and will return the list of users
            $http.get('api/getuser').success(function(users) {
                vm.users = users;

            }).error(function(error) {
                vm.error = error;
            });
        }

    }

})();
```

The authentication using facebook is successful, and I can get the token, but if request any restricted api, the server return the above error message.

My route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    //Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::get('getuser', 'AuthenticateController@index');
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
```

Using postman to get the result from restricted api works, but using browser give me the above error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a JWT? Try adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: It's the AWS server that cause me the issue. Yes I am using JWTAuth tymon/jwt-auth.